# Getting the services that are defined without Config Component

Tags: symfony

I don't find answer to my question in Google first pages. I used to define my services in YAML config files but now that I am reading the [Dependency Injection](http://symfony.com/doc/current/components/dependency_injection/introduction.html#basic-usage) chapter in Symfony Components book, I am somehow starting to understand how the base of things is done.

However I don't understand how can I `get` the service elsewhere like I did before (inside controller):

```
$object=$this->get('my_service');
```

It looks like I will always need to use `use` statements to import `Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\ContainerBuilder` and do the following:

```
use Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\ContainerBuilder;
$container = new ContainerBuilder();
// ...
$object = $container->get('my_service');
```

Am I totally right here? I thought if I avoid using the Config Component, I would make my framework more lightweight, but how can get the service without instantiating the `ContainerBuilder` class?

Thank you for your usual help.

Comment: You would want to inject the class dependency directly when you can rather than the entire service container. You will want to have the class as a construct argument in most cases for the injection.

Comment: @mr12086, thank you for your feedback. I don't ask about the case when a service depends on another service, I just want to know if it is possible to get a certain service from the container (programatically without directives) without instantiating `ContainerBuilder`. Is it possible? I edit omit the dependency injection tag from my question

Comment: I'm not sure I fully understand your questions, but here's my 2 cents. The purpose of the chapters you read are about how each of the `components` of Symfony can be used independently - hence the instance of `ContainerBuilder`. As for Symfony itself, as long as you extend either `Controller` class from `FrameworkBundle` or the `ContainerAware` class from `DependencyInjection` component your controller will receive an instance of `container`.

Comment: You're welcome. Glad I could help you.